# I am a fruit. Who am I?

Tags: steganography

> I am not on earth but on Moon,
>
> I am not sad but Angry,
>
> I am dressed so not Naked,
>
> I am not bad so Good,
>
> I am not bird so I am not Owl,

Guess which fruit I am talking about?

Comment: -1: the actual meaning of the text had nothing to do with the answer. That's the exact *opposite* of what a riddle is supposed to be.

Comment: Agree with @Deusovi - the first line is fine as m is not on earth but on moon, but others are not valid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is it:

> Mango

Because:

> The initials of the final words of each line spell MANGO

Answer (score 0):

It is

> MANGO
>
>  The initial letters of the bold words!